# How to do backup and rollback in TFS Release Management

Tags: tfs, release-management

I am new to TFS hence looking for strategies on how people do backup and rollbacks.

I would imagine it would go like any other release management system where before new release we backup the old one and keep it easy to re-deploy incase of rollback.

My application is a website running on IIS and has SQL databases. Any hints or how you've accomplished it will be helpful. Ideas on the lines of whats Tasks were created, how backups were triggered, and how rollbacks were initiated.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Sorry using TFS 2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you install the [Release Management Utility Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.utilitytasks) extension in your account, you’ll see a new task called “Rollback powershell” in the task catalog. For rollback, you’ll need to add this task to the workflow.

Regarding backup, you can add a Powershell task to perform a backup of the original files.

Here is a useful blog for your reference: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/28/implement-rollback-with-release-management-for-tfs-2015/